# Javascript return function to function definition

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could anyone explain what this function does. 
I dont understand the part where function definition parse(group) is being passed `'data'`.

```
function getData(data) {
        data = (data === undefined) ? this.defaultData() : data;

        var self = this;

        return (function parse(group) {
            return self.change('groupTo', groupExp, group);
        }(data));
    }
```

Now that I know this is an `IIFE`, what I wanna know now is whether `'arg'` is available for use within `doSomething()`

```
(function (local_arg) {
   doSomething(local_arg);
})(arg);
```

Comment: If not a dup, but [good reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript).

Comment: I suppose you simplified the code, because as represented here, it is overly complicated for something that could be very simple. Could you maybe post the (more) original code?

Comment: Read the answer to the edited question at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Function_scope).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this pattern:

```
(function (local_arg) {
   doSomething(local_arg);
})(arg);
```

...the function is immediately executed, and the parameter `local_arg` will take the value of the argument that was passed, i.e. `arg`. So the above is doing the same as just:

```
doSomething(arg);
```

In some cases where `arg` is a more complicated expression, and you need to use it multiple times, or you have the need for variables that only need to be known locally, the IIFE pattern can be useful.

Comment: Thank you @trincot .Got my answer :)

Answer (score 3):

this is not a good piece of code. I would not know where to start on the bad practices...

This function defines a function that it is not reachable from any other scope, and not reusable, just to return its call with the data argument. The outer return could be simple as

```
return self.change('groupTo', groupExp, data);
```

Comment: This is an existing piece of code that I am trying to understand.

Comment: @Abhijit yes. the `group` in `function parse(group){}` references the passed value of `data`

Answer (score 1):

if you call `getData()` function without passing any parameter then value of the data variable in function is undefined.
So at this Line ternary operator is used.

```
data = (data === undefined) ? this.defaultData() : data;
```

So it will check whether `data === undefined` condition which is true. therefore it will assign value of `this.defaultData()` to the data attribute
In short when value of `data` is `undefined` that time following is the case

```
data = this.defaultData()
```

Otheriwse if data has a value means calling function `getData("Hi")` with parameter then it will be evaluated as a

```
data = data // data = Hi
```

Now here `var self = this;` is used to preserve the context of `this` inside nested function which is mentioned below.

```
    return (function parse(group) {
        return self.change('groupTo', groupExp, group);
    }(data));
```

Without self = this if i try to use `this` in Nested function then it will point to the Global Object i.e `window` Object in JS.

In following Code `arg` is available inside the function as we are passing it in call of IIFE so it is availabel to pass in the call of doSomething function.

```
(function (local_arg) {
   doSomething(local_arg);
})(arg);
```

Comment: To Understand the How `this` behaves in JavaScript  Read this Article
http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/

Comment: Taken OP's code as it is, `this` will refer to `window` anyway.

Comment: Yeah Currently function is Outside so it will points to window . But If  this function is written in JavaScript Object then context will be change @Teemu

Comment: It's a function declaration, it is not written in an object, it can be called in the context of an object, though. `this` also will get meaning, if the function is called with `new` operator.

Comment: I was saying suppose if function is assign to the Object.
obj1 ={
gt : function(data) {
        data = (data === undefined) ? this.defaultData() : data;

        var self = this;

        return (function parse(group) {
            return self.change('groupTo', groupExp, group);
        }(data));
    }
}
Then context of `this` changes and this will points to the current JS object which is `obj1` rather than `window` object

Comment: "Assigned" to an object is not the same as "written in an object" = ). Anywy,  it is not assigned to or written in an object, it is a declared function ... As I said, It can be assigned to an object, or used as a constructor.